# Stripe PHP - Possible To Batch Uncaptured Charges?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My app has a 'tab' like system for my customers in which we create Charge objects and pass "false" to "capture". When the event has ended, we then complete all of the charges individually.

I'm wondering if the Stripe API has the ability to let us batch together a number of uncaptured charges and process them into one larger charge? I can't find anything in the API, but this link below leads me to believe it should possible?

https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-microtransactions-and-will-my-fees-be-the-same